# Production build is too large

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nginx, gzip

In my react app created using `create-react-app` the final production build comes out with a 2.3MB of JS file and 300kb of CSS file (very little CSS).

When I run the command `npm run build` which uses `react-scripts` to take build shows that is taking optimised build for production.

I even tried to force it with `npm run build --env=production`, still the same unoptimised output.

what I feel missing is uglifyjs and `minification of JS files is not being done, As I See my js files are not min.js.

Also final output says it has gzip compressed and it's size is around 400kb of js File ,if that is so how do i serve my files to improve optimisation.

P.S: I also tried some of solution where it suggested to exclude the Generation map to reduce size , but I feel that reduces the overall build size but still not the JS file individually.

Comment: Maybe it's simply a huge app?

Comment: I still feel that I missed some optimisation or I haven't enabled some config in react-build which causes to get me such huge builds. is going with serving files as gzip is the only way i got now? also how do I uglify my js files with react-build.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want a smaller bundle size you could try code splitting with webpack. For this you want to have control over your webpack configuration and therefore you would have to **eject** your `create-react-app` setup.

After this we can configure webpack in such a manner that it will uses **code splitting**. Code splitting simply produces multiple **bundels** instead of one big bundle of code with all of its dependencies. We then can on send only the bundle which is necessary for a certain page, and load all of the remaining bundles in the background.

All of this when done properly can significantly lower the initial load time of your react application.

[Here](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/) you can find how to implement code splitting

Comment: Seems like a way, I too have thought of ejecting create-react-app and make use of webpack power to reduce size and optimise further. Let me give a try at your solution